# Updating row of one table using rows of another table based on specific conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I want to update `OFFICE_ID,OFFICE_TYPE` of `FA_SUBLEDGER_MST` table, by using `OFFICE_ID,OFFICE_TYPE` from `EMPLOYEE_MST` table based on following conditions:

`EMPLOYEE_MST.SL_CODE=FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE
 EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_ID<>SL.OFFICE_ID
 OR EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE<>SL.OFFICE_TYPE
 AND EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!='DHB'.`

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST sl
SET
  (
    sl.OFFICE_ID,sl.OFFICE_TYPE
  )
  =
  (SELECT emp.OFFICE_ID,
  emp.OFFICE_TYPE
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST emp
  WHERE emp.OFFICE_ID<>sl.OFFICE_ID
  OR emp.OFFICE_TYPE<>sl.OFFICE_TYPE
  AND sl.SL_CODE      = emp.SL_CODE
  AND emp.OFFICE_TYPE!='DHB'
  )
WHERE sl.STATUS = 'A'
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST emp
  WHERE emp.OFFICE_ID<>sl.OFFICE_ID
  OR emp.OFFICE_TYPE<>sl.OFFICE_TYPE
  AND emp.SL_CODE=sl.SL_CODE  
  AND emp.OFFICE_TYPE!='DHB'
  );
```

And this:

```
UPDATE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST
SET
  (
    OFFICE_ID,
    OFFICE_TYPE
  )
  =
  (SELECT OFFICE_ID,
    OFFICE_TYPE
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST
  WHERE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_ID != EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_ID
  OR FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!  =EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE
  AND FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE      = EMPLOYEE_MST.SL_CODE
  AND EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!     ='DHB'
  ) ;
```

But both caused this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row

I also tried:

```
UPDATE
  (SELECT em.OFFICE_ID emoffid,
    SL.OFFICE_ID sloffid,
    em.OFFICE_TYPE emofftype,
    SL.OFFICE_TYPE slemofftype,
    SL.STATUS
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST em
  JOIN FA_SUBLEDGER_MST SL
  ON em.SL_CODE      =SL.SL_CODE
  WHERE em.OFFICE_ID<>SL.OFFICE_ID
  OR em.OFFICE_TYPE <>SL.OFFICE_TYPE
  AND em.OFFICE_TYPE!='DHB'
  AND SL.STATUS      ='A'
  ) t
SET t.sloffid   =t.emoffid
WHERE t.emoffid<>t.sloffid
OR t.emofftype <>t.slemofftype
AND t.emofftype!='DHB'
AND t.STATUS    ='A';
```

This caused an error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
>   01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
>   *Cause: An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which map to a non-key-preserved table.
>   *Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Both the tables contain more than 100,000 records and `OFFICE_ID` can be `1,2,3,4,5` and `OFFICE_TYPE` can be `'DE','DI','HO'`, hence they repeat frequently.

I need an Oracle query to do so. Can't use a procedure.

Would be thankful for your help.

Comment: The second one is closest, but you must refer to the main FA_SUBLEDGER_MST in the sub-query, to return only one row.

Comment: Hey thanks i gave it a second look after your comment and 
`UPDATE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST
SET
  (
    OFFICE_ID,
    OFFICE_TYPE
  )
  =
  (SELECT OFFICE_ID,OFFICE_TYPE
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST
  WHERE (FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_ID != EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_ID
  OR FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!  =EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE)
  AND FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE      = EMPLOYEE_MST.SL_CODE
  AND EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!     ='DHB'
  ) ;`
Worked. (Just added a () around OR condition.)

Comment: But the problem is that it Updates all records.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a WHERE clause too?

Comment: I tried using where clause but was unable to use `EMPLOYEE_MST` inside it.

I instead tried:
`WHERE
  (OFFICE_ID != (select OFFICE_ID from EMPLOYEE_MST where SL_CODE=FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE) and
  OFFICE_TYPE != (select OFFICE_TYPE from EMPLOYEE_MST where SL_CODE=FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE))
  AND SL_CODE = (select SL_CODE from EMPLOYEE_MST where SL_CODE=FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE)
  AND (select OFFICE_TYPE from EMPLOYEE_MST where SL_CODE=FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE)! ='DHB'  
  ;` but it gives error "single-row subquery returns more than one row".    :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found a solution:**

```
 merge into FA_SUBLEDGER_MST s1
    using (
        select SL_CODE, OFFICE_ID, OFFICE_TYPE
        from EMPLOYEE_MST
        where OFFICE_TYPE != 'DHB'
    ) emp
    on (s1.SL_CODE = emp.SL_CODE)
    when matched then update set 
        s1.OFFICE_ID = emp.OFFICE_ID,
        s1.OFFICE_TYPE = emp.OFFICE_TYPE
    where sl.STATUS = 'A'
        and (s1.OFFICE_ID <> emp.OFFICE_ID
        or  s1.OFFICE_TYPE <> emp.OFFICE_TYPE)

;
```

Orignal Thread: [Updating row of one table using rows of another table based on specific conditions *on https://dba.stackexchange.com/*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117245/updating-row-of-one-table-using-rows-of-another-table-based-on-specific-conditio)

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS:

```
 WHERE (FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_ID != EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_ID AND
        FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_TYPE !=EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE) --AND will be converted to OR by SQL Engine
  AND FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE      = EMPLOYEE_MST.SL_CODE
  AND EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!     ='DHB'
  AND sl.STATUS = 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem that some records were not being updated.
But it updates all 124,451 rows, should it update all rows?
The rows met with the above specified condition are only 4,522 rows.

Comment: Its actually setting null to all other rows that do not fulfill given condition.

Comment: You  mean the other rows (124,451 - 4,522) updated with Null?

Comment: yes.. All (124,451 - 4,522) rows value was changed to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST
SET sl.OFFICE_ID = em.OFFICE_ID
,sl.OFFICE_TYPE = em.OFFICE_TYPE
FROM FA_SUBLEDGER_MST sl
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_MST em ON em.SL_CODE      =SL.SL_CODE
  WHERE em.OFFICE_ID<>SL.OFFICE_ID
  OR em.OFFICE_TYPE <>SL.OFFICE_TYPE
  AND em.OFFICE_TYPE!='DHB'
  AND SL.STATUS      ='A'
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see the Oracle tag, this is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
UPDATE FA_SUBLEDGER_MST
SET
  (
    OFFICE_ID,
    OFFICE_TYPE
  )
  =
  (SELECT OFFICE_ID,
    OFFICE_TYPE
  FROM EMPLOYEE_MST
 WHERE ....... 
  ) 
  WHERE (FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_ID != EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_ID AND
        FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.OFFICE_TYPE !=EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE) 
  AND FA_SUBLEDGER_MST.SL_CODE      = EMPLOYEE_MST.SL_CODE
  AND EMPLOYEE_MST.OFFICE_TYPE!     ='DHB'
  AND sl.STATUS = 'A' ;
```

Comment: The problem is that in the where clause under the Update query  `EMPLOYEE_MST.` can not be identified by SQL.

Its giving a error as: `SQL Error: ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEE_MST"."OFFICE_TYPE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
`

Comment: if you are using Oracle, You should use lower case for identifiers(table/column)